ETH to RXS token exchange showing incorrect balance in Coinbase wallet
I exchanged ETH for RXS finance at 0.06 and 0.08. About $5200 total worth. I have just above 62000 RXS tokens showing in my Ethereum Coinbase wallet after all fees, but value balance only shows $430 dollars even though the pre-sale is already at 0.15. What am I am missing here? Shouldn’t I be seeing a value balance equivalent to the current value of the presale for each token. 0.15 X 62000? I used the browser on Coinbase wallet app to do the exchange.

This is a glitch in Coinbase. The value should technically be $0 since it hasn’t been released yet. If you check Etherscan on your wallet address you’ll see the correct amount of tokens and a value of $0 currently
This is what support at rexas states

Can you provide the link to RXS support. Can’t find it. Thanks

Live chat on rexas webpage
